# Android Root. Permission denied

Tags: android, linux, безопасность, root

Пытаюсь из приложения скопировать файл, который находится в чужом пакете приложения в папку. Мне отказывает в доступе, при том, что я прописываю `su` перед копированием, копирование делаю из Runtime.exec `cp <curFile> <destFile>`. Root не всемогущий ? Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько поспешно я задал вопрос, проблема легко решилась, нужно было после выполнения `su` сохранить `OutputStream` в котором оно было исполнено, и потом в него же записать следующие команды, я же по использовал новый `Runtime.exec()`.
Вообщем для использования возможностей `su`, команды нужно выполнять в созданном `su` потоке